# Compablity issue with Chrome Web Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, compatibility

We have developed a website using HTML, css and javascriipting. When we open it in Mozilla firefox then we get correct display for the webpage but when we open it in Chrome browser then we gets a gap between news and event box and the images which we put just below it.

[Link for the website is here.](http://www.teciexsolutions.in/index.html)

I am attaching some screen shots to get a clear picture for the issue.
[image: Display in Mozilla Firefox browser]

[image: Display in Google Chrome browser]

Comment: its just work fine , which version of chrome you r using

Comment: @Arun_SE Chrome Version-  40.0.2214.93 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the height of **`marquee`** tag. In firefox, it is auto adjusting the height while in chrome it is taking some other height.
One workaround will be to give Inline height to **`marquee`** .eg:- give height:164 px.

Comment: I changed the marquee - style="height:;width:; margin-left:; background:; padding-top:11px; . But still it won't work

Comment: use this    <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="4" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" style="height: 164px;">

Comment: Which marquee did the change in display? Because i can see two marquee tags in the source code? Is there any documentation available for this

Comment: The marquee which is inside the  **blockquote** tag (the first one).The marquee element provides a way for browsers to render text that moves across the page without having to resort to JavaScript techniques ..It is  just like any other tag ...